# Regex select last instance in dynamic string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to do a mass find and replace in visual studio 2012 using regEx. The strings I'm trying to update have a set beginning and end but vary in content

```
z.LocalizedLanguage["copy"]
z.LocalizedLanguage["paste"]
z.LocalizedLanguage["warehouse"]
```

My initial plan was to do it in two phases:

1) Match on the full set using the following regEx but modifying only the ']' with ')':

```
(z\.LocalizedLanguage\[\".*\"\])
```

z.LocalizedLanguage["copy"] to z.LocalizedLanguage["copy")

2) Match on the 'z.LocalizedLanguage[' and replace it with a separate string: 'z.ll('

Due to the dyanmic nature of the text between the quotations, I can't manage to find a way to limit my regex match to only the trailing ']'. Is it possible to run a sub-match on the results from the initial match?

Comment: can you post a sample of the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the lazy `?` operator

```
(z\.LocalizedLanguage\[\".*?\"\])
```